# lastIndexOf() JavaScript default value if the fromIndex parameter is omitted

Tags: javascript

Within JavaScript you have the `lastIndexOf(string,[fromIndex])` method.

The `fromIndex` is an optional parameter. If the `fromIndex` is omitted, is the default value 0 or is it `string.length - 1`?

Comment: Look in the specs, maybe? They are openly available. Asking other people to look stuff up in the specs for you is rude, plain and simple.

Comment: I think you can find the answer from js doc **by yourself**.

Comment: Not hard to look this up yourself https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf You are expected to do basic research before asking questions here

Comment: If i understood the spec, do you think I will be asking on here??? The spec is confusing. E.g. here is an example: searchValue − A string representing the value to search for.

fromIndex − The location within the calling string to start the search from. It can be any integer between 0 and the length of the string. The default value is 0.

Comment: This is what mozilla is saying: The index at which to start searching backwards in the string. Starting with this index, the left part of the string will be searched. It can be any integer. The default value is +Infinity. If fromIndex >= str.length, the whole string is searched. If fromIndex < 0,  the behavior will be the same as if it would be 0. Is it 0 or string.length-1

Comment: Indicate that you have indeed looked it up, cite the passage you don't understand and ask a question about it. Back it up with some testing code you wrote to understand the behavior of the function and write a sentence or two about what aspects of your testing code confuse you. That's how you should ask such a question (any question, really, but such a question especially). It avoids appearing lazy, when in fact you were not. Don't take it hard, next time simply put some more beef into your question.

Comment: Why did someone voted to close this as "unclear what you're asking"? It's perfectly clear what the OP is asking.

Comment: I was wondering the same thing!

Comment: The first example you chose was some random search result from tutorialspoint.com. Don't trust these websites, they are not reliable. Mozilla's MDN is reliable. But **authoritative** is [the ECMAScript spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.5.4.8), and nothing else. When in doubt, look there.

Comment: Thank you Tomalak. I know understand it is the length of the string.

Comment: When they say a string is searched from back to front, what does that mean because to me it seems like its searched front to back?

Comment: @user7007558 The exact search algorithm is implementation-dependent. The spec only requires returning the largest possible nonnegative integer which fulfills some condition. So back to front makes more sense.

Comment: So does this method search in reverse order?

Comment: @user7007558 Not necessarily, but probably yes.

Answer (score 0):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf#Parameters):

> The default value is `+Infinity`.

This means that by default the whole string is searched.

Answer (score 0):

For arrays it's `length - 1`:

> [**Array.prototype.lastIndexOf ( *searchElement* [ , *fromIndex* ] )**](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-array.prototype.lastindexof)
>
> 4. If argument *fromIndex* was passed, let *n* be ?
>      [ToInteger](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-tointeger)(*fromIndex*); else let *n* be *len*-1.

For strings its Infinity:

> [**String.prototype.lastIndexOf ( *searchString* [ , *position* ] )**](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-string.prototype.lastindexof)
>
> 4. Let *numPos* be ? [ToNumber](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-tonumber)(*position*). (If *position* is
>      **undefined**, this step produces the value **NaN**.)
> 5. If *numPos* is **NaN**, let *pos* be +∞; otherwise, let *pos* be
>      [ToInteger](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-tointeger)(*numPos*)

But note it's then clamped by a maximum:

> 7. Let *start* be [min](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-algorithm-conventions)([max](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-algorithm-conventions)(*pos*, 0), *len*)

So it becomes `length`, not `length - 1`. This way you can find empty strings at the end:

```
'abcd'.lastIndexOf('d');    // 3
'abcd'.lastIndexOf('d', 3); // 3  --  can be length-1

'abcd'.lastIndexOf('');     // 4
'abcd'.lastIndexOf('', 3);  // 3  --  cannot be length-1
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but on the w3c website it says: startIndex  : The location in the string to search the specified value. Location value is an integer between 0 and the length of the string. The default value is 0. Is it not 0 then?

Comment: @user7007558 W3C [has no power here](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/you-have-no-power-here). This is part of ECMAScript, not web standards.

Comment: @user7007558 By the way, it seems you quote w3resource. They are in no way affiliated or related to W3C.